# Can't pass around returned object from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am picking up a project started by a peer, and having trouble with an API call.
This is my angular controller:

```
angular.module('oowli').factory('Note', ['$http', function($http) {
  var Note = function(data) {
    angular.extend(this, data);
  };

  Note.prototype.save = function() {
    var note = this;
    return $http.post('/notes', this).then(function(response) {
      note = response.data;
    }, function(error) {
      return error;
    });
  };

  return Note;
}]);
```

and the call is executed in this function:

```
var saveNote = function(Note, scope){
        return function(span, phrase){
            var noteObj = new Note({
                user: scope.global.user._id,
                content: span.innerText
            });
            noteObj.save().then(function(){
                console.log(noteObj);
            });

        };
    };
```

problem is, after saving the note, noteObj is the original, not the one that comes back from the server (with an _id field).
Debugging on the `Note.prototype.save`, `response.data` comes with the _id;

I need to know how to have access to the returned Note object, in the saveNote function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the new object to the local variable 'note' in the Note.prototype.save function, but then not doing anything with it.

The quickest solution is to copy the properties of the returned object to your note rather than assign to it, so instead of:

```
note = response.data;
```

This might work:

```
angular.copy(response.data, note)
```

In general though I don't like the approach of having the Note class responsible for saving itself.  I would create a note service that saves the object.